# What is effect of hidden files or folder on UDP connection

Tags: filesystems, windows-firewall, udp

I am running MFC application. All was working fine.But few files and folders were hidden.Now that application is getting collapsed on UDP connection event. I have checked firewall settings also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually UDP was failing because the logfile I was writing  through my application was hidden. So due to not having access, my thread was collapsing resulting collapsing of UDP connection.